# Expresiones regulares - devolver listas y números que no pertenezcan a otra estructura de datos

Tags: python, string, python-3.7, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

¿Cómo puedo conseguir las estructuras de datos que se encuentran en un `string` sin que pertenezca a su vez a otra estructura?

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código tengo definidos los patrones para encontrar estructuras de datos y si una lista contiene números, esos números aparecerán tanto en el patrón de lista como en el de números:

```py
import re
patrones = [
        r"\[.*\]",      # Patrón para identificar listas
        r"\{.*\}",      # Patrón para identificar diccionarios
        r"\(.*\)",      # Patrón para identificar tuplas
        r"[0-9]+",      # Patrón para identificar números
        r"[\"]\w*[\"]"  # Patrón para identificar strings
    ]

string='12, 2, 3, "aa4" en lista es [12, 2, 3, "aa4"]'

print([re.findall(patron, string) for patron in patrones])
```

Y al ejecutarlo:

```py
[['[12, 2, 3, "aa4"]'], [], [], ['12', '2', '3', '4', '12', '2', '3', '4'], ['"aa4"', '"aa4"']]
```

Comment: Yo no me complicaría tanto. Hazlo en dos pasos, primero localiza las listas y, en un segundo paso, localiza números donde no hayas detectado listas. Además aún se puede complicar más, con listas anidadas. Si necesitas hacer un parser, igual tendrías que buscar alguna herramienta especializada.